# how save data from API - flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I'm workin on API request.I would like to save all data recieved from API and reuse it in second method as parametres .

API response  :

```
{
    "code": 0,
    "message": " success",
    "data": {
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 14,
                "boxIdentifiant": 1924589682265255,
                "user_id": 53,
                "boxName": "box12",
                "proprietaire": 21625147147,
                "adress_circulation": "Tokyo",
                "gps_lat": null,
                "gps_long": null,
                "status": "normal"
            }
        ]
    },
    "error": [],
    "status": 200
}
```

I recieve data above by this method :

```
Future<UserBox> fetchBoxes() async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String token = localStorage.getString('access_token');
    await checkInternet();
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
    };
    var url = Uri.parse(ApiUtil.GET_ALL_BOXES);
    var response = await http.get(url, headers: headers);
    var body = jsonDecode(response.body);
    var data = body['data']['data'];

    List<BoxModel> boxes =
        List.generate(data.length, (index) => BoxModel.fromJson(data[index]));
    final userbox = UserBox()..boxes = boxes;
    return userbox;
  }
```

How i can save all data ?

Answer (score 0):

```
UserBox data = await fetchBoxes();
secondMethod(data);
```